# How to get the dollar symbol to come after words?

Tags: python, python-2.7, file

This is my code:

```
a = open("1.txt","r+")
b = open("2.txt","r+")
for i in a.readlines(): 
    io=str(i)+"$"
    e = b.writelines(io)

a.close()
b.close()
```

I want `$` comes after the words but it comes before them.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGKbP.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. **Don't post images of code or error messages.** Read [why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Instead copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

Comment: Welcome to SO ! You might also read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), currently it is impossible to know what your problem is when reading the title of your question

Comment: Please do edit this question to be clearer, so we can reopen it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this, using context managers:

```
with open("1.txt", "r") as inFile:
    with open("2.txt", "w") as outFile:
        for line in inFile:
            outFile.write(line.strip() + "$\n")
```

To get back to your code, you can strip the last character `\n` using slicing and then add `$\n` in the end:

```
a = open("1.txt","r+")
b = open("2.txt","r+")
for i in a.readlines(): 
    io=i[:-1] + "$\n"
    e = b.write(io)

a.close()
b.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

It happened because each line contains `\n` at the end.

Change `io=str(i)+"$"` to:

```
io = i.rstrip() + "$" + '\n'
```